# Cannot drop priorly modified new table in execute block

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm not well acquainted with FB database and its subtleties.
On script executing, the problem occurres:

```
EXECUTE ibeblock
AS
BEGIN

-- 1. Create temporary table
execute statement 'recreate GLOBAL TEMPORARY table TMPTBL (ID bigint) /*on commit delete rows*/;';
commit;

-- 2. dummy fill of temporary table
insert into tmptbl (ID)
values (0xFE);
commit; -- not necessary

-- 3. perform some actions...

-- 4. Delete temporary table
execute statement 'drop table TMPTBL;';
commit; -- FAILURE!

END
```

The idea of script is primitive: 1) create temporary table; 2) fill it with records; 3) perform actions on other DB objects using populated records; 4) drop temp table.
For simulation, step-3 is useless (skipped). Step-4 leads to an error *on commit*: "This operation is not defined for system tables. unsuccessful metadata update. object TABLE "TMPTBL" is in use.".
Neither triggers nor constraints are applied for the table. Obviously, there should be nothing locking temp table.

Help, please, with resolution. Hopefully I missed something.
P.S.: FB 2.5, IBExpert 2017.12.13.1 used as DB managing tool

Comment: Are you sure `step 3` doesn't lock the table? Is this problem really preproduces without `step 3`?

Comment: @Evgeny The insert locks the table with an existence lock. The OP is attempting to drop the table in the same transaction that used it. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been forced again by devops guys to find robust solution to provide DB structure upgrades. Requirements: safely combine DDL and DML statements; ability to create temporary tables (for heavy selections); leave no garbage. Of course, upgrade is handled within single connection.

Referencing to the clues given by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) a deeper insight and lots of experiments were made.

Here is template filescript that really worked out (isql native utility used):

```
SET TERM #;

-- 1. Create temporary table
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  execute statement 'recreate GLOBAL TEMPORARY table TMPTBL (ID bigint) /*on commit preserve rows*/;';
END#
commit#

-- Data manipulations
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
  declare xid bigint;
BEGIN

-- 2. dummy fill of temporary table
begin
  insert into TMPTBL (ID) values (0xFE);
end

-- 3. perform some actions...
for
  select tt.ID
  from TMPTBL tt
  into :xid
do
begin
  -- use :xid var
end

END#
commit#


-- 4. Delete temporary table
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
BEGIN
  execute statement 'drop table TMPTBL;';
END#
commit#

SET TERM ;#
```

Might be usefull for someone.
Damn, Firebird do drives crazy!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. A global temporary table is intended as a permanent object, it is just the content that is temporary (either for transaction or connection duration). So normally you would create a global temporary table once, and not drop it, but instead reuse its definition.
2. Although you technically can execute DDL using `execute statement`, you are not supposed to, and it is not guaranteed to work. Your code is specifically an example of one of the things that will not work.

   The problem here, is that you are trying to drop the table in the same transaction that used it (though to be honest, I'm surprised the insert even worked, because normally you can't insert into a table that was created in the same transaction).

   The insert you executed on `TMPTBL` will mark the table in use, and given the transaction isn't committed yet, you can't drop the table: it is in use.
3. You shouldn't call commit in PSQL code (to be honest, I thought this wasn't even possible).

In short, you need to rethink how you use global temporary tables: define it once, and do not use `execute statement` to create it, but create it separately.

If you do want to create and drop it and not retain the definition of the global temporary table, then create it **before** the `execute block`, commit, then the `execute block` (with only the inserts and the 'perform some actions'), commit, and then drop it (and commit).

Alternatively, you might get away with executing the create using [`execute statement ... with autonomous transaction`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt-wautonomous), the inserts and the 'perform some actions' in another `execute statement ... with autonomous transaction`, and finally the drop in yet another `execute statement ... with autonomous transaction`. However that makes your code very brittle, and this is not a recommend approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for spent efforts!